# A condition on parametrisations of regular surfaces

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Let $\Sigma$ be a regular surface and let $p \in \Sigma$. According to Manfredo do Carmo in his $\textit{Differential geometry of curves and surfaces}$, one thing we should expect of a local parametrisation $\phi$ from some open $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ onto an open neighbourhood $V$ of $p$ in $\Sigma$ is that $\phi$ should be a homeomorphism. But he then goes on to say: "That is, $\phi^{-1}$ is the restriction to $V$ of a continuous map $f: W \to \mathbb{R}^2$ for an open $W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$".

Isn't this latter stipulation stronger than requiring $\phi$ to be a homeomorphism? I can see how you could obtain it if you assume that $V$ is closed in some larger open set $Y$, $V \subseteq Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, by the Tietze extension theorem (take $W = Y$), but we have no grounds for assuming that. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joshua, you probably won't be happy with this answer, but here it is. Ultimately, the implicit function theorem will tell us that a smooth surface locally can be written as a graph of the form $z=F(x,y)$ for a smooth function $f$ (or $y=G(x,z)$ or $x=H(y,z)$). That is there is a neighborhood $W$ of $p$ in $\mathbb R^3$ whose intersection with the surface $S$ consists of points $(x,y,z)$ with $z=f(x,y)$ for $(x,y)\in U\subset\mathbb R^2$. But then any continuous function $\phi$ on $V=S\cap W$ can be extended to $W$ by setting $f(x,y,z) = \phi(x,y,f(x,y))$.

Comment: Hmm. I like this answer as intuition, but it's kind of circular unless everything lying behind the word "ultimately" does not assume $\phi$ is a homeomorphism in anything more than the usual sense. At any rate, it seems clear that it was a leap for do Carmo to use the phrase "that is...". Would you agree?

Comment: There's a similar issue in Guillemin and Pollack, where they deal only with submanifolds of $\mathbb R^n$ and define smoothness of a map $f\colon X\to\mathbb R$ for any subset $X\subset\mathbb R^n$ in terms of a local smooth extension. I think DoCarmo suffers from trying to write about manifold theory for so many pages when he really doesn't need it all for a first course on surfaces. Certainly he's trying to specify what the subspace topology on the surface should be. But what he says is valid because he's working with a $C^1$ surface, not an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because I can see how you'd deduce the result without any circularity, and it anyway resolves my question of whether the assumption is trivial. One more question: From your bio you're someone who has worked with differential geometry for many years. Can you recommend a good alternative to do Carmo as an introduction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a less advanced treatment, download my notes from my webpage. If you want something more advanced, tell me your background.

Comment: Hi again, and sorry for my extremely delayed response. I completely forgot about this question. My background includes a decent amount of analysis and some topology. How do you think I'd be suited to the first volume of Spivak?

Comment: Serious multivariable analysis with inverse/implicit function theorems? If you want to lesrn differential geometry and not generalities about manifolds, Spivak Volume I is a ton of baggage, and curves and surfaces come in Volume III. You could jump in there and ho back as needed. Boothby is a bit more concise. There are lots of other options, but not clear what precisely you want, I guess :)

Comment: Not multivariable analysis, but I'm familiar with inverse and implicit function theorems yes. If you have time, my course outline is here: http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/UG/SM/MATH3968/r/outline.pdf . If you think of a text you'd recommend above do Carmo for that content, please do say. Thanks again.

Comment: Joshua: Since you haven't yet learned differential forms, you might find R.W.R. Darling's *Differential Forms and Connections* an interesting follow-up to doCarmo. You might also like the style of Klingenberg's *A Course in Differential Geometry* more. For some exposure to interesting algebraic topology but not as off the deep end as several volumes of Spivak, again based on differential forms, there's Singer and Thorpe's *Lecture notes on Elementary Topology and Geometry*.